cannot estimate gas of route swap with Uniswap v3
I'm currently trying to process a swap with Uniswap v3 by forking the example of the documentation (https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/guides/swaps/routing). I'm swapping on Base Mainnet (chain id: 8453)
Here's my transaction content:
{
  data: '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',
  to: '0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x038d7ea4c68000', _isBigNumber: true },
  from: '0x1c08A20E21Fb232007fA3B6e914c74De45d3e563',
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x174876e800', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x174876e800', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x033450', _isBigNumber: true }
}

Here is my code :
export async function executeRoute(
  route: SwapRoute
): Promise<TransactionState> {
  const walletAddress = getWalletAddress();
  const provider = getProvider();

  if (!walletAddress || !provider) {
    throw new Error("Cannot execute a trade without a connected wallet");
  }

  const tokenApproval = await getTokenTransferApproval(CurrentConfig.tokens.in);

  console.log(tokenApproval, "tokenApproval wefiuweof80923");

  // Fail if transfer approvals do not go through
  if (tokenApproval !== TransactionState.Sent) {
    return TransactionState.Failed;
  }

  console.log(
    ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.001", 18),
    ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.001", 18).toNumber(),
    'ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.001", 18) weou9273fub2o3fwefc'
  );

  const tx = {
    data: route.methodParameters?.calldata,
    to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.001", 18),
    from: walletAddress,
    maxFeePerGas: ethers.BigNumber.from(MAX_FEE_PER_GAS),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.BigNumber.from(MAX_PRIORITY_FEE_PER_GAS),
    gasLimit: ethers.BigNumber.from(210000),
  };

  const res = await sendTransaction(tx);

  return res;
}

Here are the errors :
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x1c08A20E21Fb232007fA3B6e914c74De45d3e563","gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x033450"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x174876e800"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x174876e800"},"to":"0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x038d7ea4c68000"},"data":"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","accessList":null}, error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":96,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}\n","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x33450\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x174876e800\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x174876e800\",\"value\":\"0x38d7ea4c68000\",\"from\":\"0x1c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e563\",\"to\":\"0x2626664c2603336e57b271c5c0b26f421741e481\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":96,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://public.stackup.sh/api/v1/node/base-mainnet"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:78:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:642:20)
    at step (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'execution reverted',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x1c08A20E21Fb232007fA3B6e914c74De45d3e563',
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x033450', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x174876e800', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x174876e800', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x038d7ea4c68000', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '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',
    accessList: null
  },
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":96,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}\n", error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x33450\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x174876e800\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x174876e800\",\"value\":\"0x38d7ea4c68000\",\"from\":\"0x1c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e563\",\"to\":\"0x2626664c2603336e57b271c5c0b26f421741e481\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":96,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://public.stackup.sh/api/v1/node/base-mainnet", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
      at Logger.makeError (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at /Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/src.ts/index.ts:341:28
      at step (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":96,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}\n',
    error: Error: execution reverted
        at getResult (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:142:28)
        at processJsonFunc (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/src.ts/index.ts:383:22)
        at /Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/src.ts/index.ts:320:42
        at step (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (/Users/corentin/Desktop/sniper/final/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: -32000,
      data: undefined
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"gas":"0x33450","maxFeePerGas":"0x174876e800","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x174876e800","value":"0x38d7ea4c68000","from":"0x1c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e563","to":"0x2626664c2603336e57b271c5c0b26f421741e481","data":"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"}],"id":96,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'https://public.stackup.sh/api/v1/node/base-mainnet'
  }
}

Do you know why does it cannot estimate the gas? The approval with the same amount (0.001) works perfectly.
Many thanks for your help!! :)

It can't estimate because the call would fail, it's a general error. There isn't a v3 uni router on base that I know of there are universal routers. Which are called via execute function and require a different type of approval process. See here and similar : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/163682/issue-swapping-with-universal-router-smart-contract-on-base-chain

Thanks for your response @Maka , i'm currently using SwapRouter02 for the address of the router (from https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments/base-deployments). Hence do i've to use a uni router and then doing my script in another chain?

No I don't think so actually. There is a contract with v3 router functions at that address: https://basescan.org/address/0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481 Can you add what the SwapRoute parameter is to your question, while I simulate your calldata and see if I can narrow down the cause of revert.

There doesn't seem to be a v2 pair with those two tokens, it's computing this one, then trying to call reserves: https://basescan.org/address/0xc103fae6eef88367e7058b9ba9afa40907cde3c5

Seems a bit going on. Looks like swapExactTokensForTokens is the the first function being called, which is for v2 swaps.
But you refer to v3 on several occasions, and there doesn't seem to be a v2 pair with liquidity for weth and this beni token:
"caller":{
"address":"0x1c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e563"
"balance":"10665104772278513"
}
"input":{
"factory":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
"tokenA":"0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006"
"tokenB":"0xde7a416ac821c77478340eebaa21b68297025ef3"
}
"output":{
"pair":"0xc103fae6eef88367e7058b9ba9afa40907cde3c5"
}

function _swap(address[] memory path, address _to) private {
        for (uint256 i; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
            (address input, address output) = (path[i], path[i + 1]);
            (address token0, ) = UniswapV2Library.sortTokens(input, output);
            IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factoryV2, input, output));
            uint256 amountInput;
            uint256 amountOutput;
            // scope to avoid stack too deep errors
            {
                (uint256 reserve0, uint256 reserve1, ) = pair.getReserves(); // <-- REVERT here
//...

There is a v3 pair with fee 10000:

https://basescan.org/address/0x396aAE958cc877B856A587EA7020154486ecFC88

Which has a couple thousand dollars liquidity.
But in your calldata you are initiating the v2 swap:
0x5ae401dc
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000665c45fb
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e4
472b43f3 <-- Here
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005af3107a4000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000610eeb161296a82ea
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080
0000000000000000000000001c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e563
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
0000000000000000000000004200000000000000000000000000000000000006
000000000000000000000000de7a416ac821c77478340eebaa21b68297025ef3
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000


https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x472b43f3


Simulating the swap with v3 calldata at the same router, from your address, shows it can work or you:
0x04e45aaf0000000000000000000000004200000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000de7a416ac821c77478340eebaa21b68297025ef300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027100000000000000000000000001c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e56300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005af3107a400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000


https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x04e45aaf

{
"amountIn":"100000000000000"
"amountOutMinimum":"0"
"fee":"10000"
"recipient":"0x1c08a20e21fb232007fa3b6e914c74de45d3e563"
"sqrtPriceLimitX96":"0"
"tokenIn":"0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006"
"tokenOut":"0xde7a416ac821c77478340eebaa21b68297025ef3"
}



So much thanks Maka for your help! It looks like uniswap's library chooses automatically for v2.. idk where to ask v3 process to the lib since i copied/pasted the example code of the doc in uni v3..
here is how i generate my route, did i do sth wrong? https://hastebin.com/share/otisirurag.javascript
here are the last logs i've of my code: https://hastebin.com/share/qukecicadu.ruby (looks weird since the route can get the estimation but not the provider)

Have never used the sdk to make swaps, so the abstraction is a bit confusing. Where is the call to executeRoute function at line 61, can not see where you are passing the route arg to the function, to see what route is being given. Is there another script?

generateRoute() seems to apply the correct trade type. But it doesn't seem like the correct method params are with the route that is being passed, so am wondering if the SwapRoute returned by generateRoute is definitely the one being given to executeRoute. Else maybe those params need to be set explicitly. Another option could be to encode the calldata you need with a router instance and set that as the data field.

That should be because i was trying to swap a token focused on uni v2. will try with uni v3 tokens. meanwhile here is the index.ts code where i execute all functions : https://hastebin.com/share/xayipufisa.typescript

Just tried with USDbC on 0xd9aaec86b65d86f6a7b5b1b0c42ffa531710b6ca and not forgetting to change decimals to 6 but still the same..

There are quite a lot of layers to the sdk, and am totally unfamiliar. Will spend a bit of time looking through to see if can understand what it wants from you.
I have lots of more direct examples of v3, and base swaps here: https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/blob/main/v3exactOutput.py.
There is also the case of approving a token for swap when there is none of the token at your address, you are passing a msg.value in the first example so router will wrap the weth for you (you don't need to approve when going from the native coin). But I don't see usdc/any tokens at your address.

Many many thanks Maka you're the best! Yes I currently only have some eth on my balance for testing. will see tomorrow your examples from your github!

You can estimate gas manually and build your transaction:
const tx = {
    data: route.methodParameters?.calldata,
    to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.001", 18),
    from: walletAddress,
    maxFeePerGas: ethers.BigNumber.from(MAX_FEE_PER_GAS),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.BigNumber.from(MAX_PRIORITY_FEE_PER_GAS),
//    gasLimit: ethers.BigNumber.from(210000),
  };

//  Lines added:
    const gasLimit=await provider.estimateGas(tx);
    tx["gasLimit"] = ethers.BigNumber.from(gasLimit);

